# Can we preserve the EXIF data of AI-generated images?

Tags: feature-request, imgur

In response to [an issue SPArcheon raised on mSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390509/308065):

> PS: and just to add insult to injury, I just realized that Stack Exchange Imgur strips the Exif metadata from pictures: something that is very good to do in most cases since you don't want to include the metadata in your photos or diffused pictures, but it would become a limitation in the rare case you wanted to keep the Diffusion setting information when posting an answer/question on this new site.

With the current state of the tooling, that EXIF data is the only thing we have that *remotely* resembles attribution. Not all tools bother adding it, but for those that do, it seems wasteful and wrong to strip it.

It would be *really great* if, while uploading images, we could preserve the EXIF data in some way.

- Perhaps a setting when uploading files to not strip EXIF data, automatically enabled if it's clearly a generated image (requires a favour from Imgur).
- Or, something that extracts the EXIF data and inserts it into the post as a table, in the same way that Markdown for the image is inserted.

Comment: btw, I said "realized" but now that you made me noticed it, "remembered" would be a better word. I already knew that, but it didn't caught my mind until then that this site may want in some case to preserve the EXIF data.

Comment: @SPArcheon RE [SirBenet's answer](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/a/35/10): Do you have examples where it's _actually_ EXIF data?

Comment: Practically speaking, how big of an issue is this? Is this a nice-to-have thing?

Comment: @SpencerG Well, it _might_ turn out to be a legal liability thing, further down the line. Depends how grey areas of copyright law get resolved. Other than that, though, it's a nice-to-have: when it's relevant, either we can bother the OP to provide the details, or it gets closed as “unclear what you're asking”.

Comment: note that stripping EXIF data has security/privacy benefits. a lot of people don't even know that their camera may put location data with the files. a site policy of putting things like diffusion settings with images can be site and manually enforced.

Comment: @starball That's probably a better way of dealing with the situation.

Comment: @SpencerG would be useful if you could get someone to answer [this related question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391435/exactly-what-metadata-is-preserved-when-uploading-an-image-on-the-network) too

Comment: I forgot to say, I think it'd be simplest to implement if the relevant and desired EXIF data just be specified in the text/body of the post above or below the image. And that way it's also very visible to the reader.

Comment: @starball I've extrapolated your suggestion into another meta question: [Must generated material be accompanied by its prompt?](https://genai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/49/10)

Answer (score 5):

The two frontends I'm aware of that store metadata in generated images do so in **PNG text chunks**, which are preserved so long as the image doesn't go over the limit where it gets JPEG'd (whereas on Stack Overflow for Teams, which hosts its own images rather than using Imgur, the image never gets JPEG'd so always keeps its data).

[image: A bottle containing a nighttime scene]

The above image contains ComfyUI metadata. You should be able to download it then drag it into the interface to load the workflow used to create it.

[image: A tomato]

The above image contains Automatic1111 metadata. You should be able to download it, drag it into the prompt box, then click the blue arrow button ("Read generation parameters from prompt [...]") to set parameters used to create it.

---

In the future, if the site grows big enough to justify a custom feature, it might be nice to have some indication of the image having metadata with a link to a help page explanation:

[image]

Comment: For sake of transparency, I have mentioned your message on a Meta.SE question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/391435/exactly-what-metadata-is-preserved-when-uploading-an-image-on-the-network). I am trying to get the staff to clarify what is preserved and when.

Comment: I am trying to see if I can get a confirmation from the staff about what is removed and when. Can I borrow your tomato picture for my question on Meta.SE?

Comment: @SPArcheon Sure