# Must generated material be accompanied by its prompt?

Tags: discussion, rules

There are a couple of reasons we might want this:

- Many generative systems were “trained” on large, scraped datasets. Were they produced illegally? Well, the legal situation of current GenAI practices is unclear: whether generated artefacts are considered derivative works is one aspect that's up in the air.

  The contents of this site is licensed [Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) – and it's already dubious whether we're *allowed* to license generated material that way. The state of the art doesn't really do attribution (though [that might be changing](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.06962v1)). Some companies refuse even to disclose their training dataset. The situation isn't *great*. Providing what information we *do* have is better than nothing: it makes it *that bit less* likely that we'll have to delete large swathes of the site, months or years down the line.
- It can be very hard to answer questions [without being able to reproduce the same conditions as the answerer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390509/308065). This information – enough to re-generate the material, if a PRNG seed is provided – could be our equivalent of [the MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Should we:

- require that *all* the user-accessible information about the generation process is provided;
- require *some* specific set of information is provided;
- require that *complete source information* must be provided, such that the same image (up to noise) can be reproduced from it:

  - with exceptions for SaaSS systems that don't expose this information;
  - no exceptions: i.e., systems that cannot be run deterministically cannot be demonstrated *by example* on this site (though they'd still be on-topic);
  - with exceptions for models trained only on public domain data / data whose copyright holders have consented to such use;
  - with exceptions for models trained only on ineligible-for-copyright data / data whose authors have consented to use without attribution;

where generative material is provided? Should we require this:

- *all* of the time?
- just for questions? (though I can't think of a circumstance where a good answer would want to *omit* this information)
- only for some types of generated material?
- only in certain circumstances?

Information about the generation process might include:

- A citation for the model (publisher, brand name, version number, date accessed)
- The parameters of the model:

  - Prompts
  - Diffusion settings
  - Top-p and temperature settings
  - etc.
- Input provided in intermediate stages:

  - The mask used for regeneration / inpainting
  - Edits made before generating another paragraph
  - etc.
- PRNG algorithm and seed

Answer (score 2):

For specific debugging questions, the asker should provide enough information to reproduce the issue. This won't necessarily be a pre-determined "specific set of information". I'd have a personal preference towards the image metadata that can be read by one of the FOSS frontends.

In many other cases, images may just be provided to demonstrate some general principle, like how [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/8964) on Graphic Design uses an image of some font characters to illustrate terminology. It would be neat to let people reproduce those examples deterministically, but it's not required for the answer to be useful and (especially without some site feature supporting it) would be prohibitively cumbersome to provide a full workflow graph under each image. Providing model name may be more realistic.

Comment: This is a pragmatic approach to the _second_ reason, but it doesn't address the first (legal / attribution). Do you think this isn't a concern, or is it just something you (like me) aren't qualified to comment on?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Last part would also apply to legal concerns - providing full deterministic workflow seems unnecessary and impractical, mentioning the models used could work. Though, if some ruling against machine learning on public data results in illegality of ChatGPT/Google Translate/etc., there'd probably need to be significantly larger changes to the site anyway (including evaluating whether it's still feasible/useful).

Comment: Providing a full deterministic workflow is enough to determine which _parts_ of a model were involved in the generation, which might (in the future) be able to be used to compute proper attribution.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 "determine which [...]" - Not convinced this will emerge or fundamentally makes sense. Impact of a training image on model weights is less than a byte of information on average for SD and likely spread among many unpredictable indirect effects ("made oak wood 0.7% smoother, reduced crab frequency, ..."). Even if technically feasible, to my understanding copyright infringement would usually be determined on the published content (so can still catch overfitting on heavily duplicated images). IMO, full deterministic workflow requirement is too big of a burden for a dubious possibility.

Comment: "wouldn't rule against Open Assistant" - Going off their [roadmap presentation](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1n7IrAOVOqwdYgiYrXc8Sj0He8krn5MVZO_iLkCjTtu0) - they're bootstrapping off of GPT-3 and also collecting from "Quora, StackOverflow, appropriate subreddits" and "filter Twitter for good data". I also don't think "it wouldn't be too hard to modify Firefox Translations" [to learn without public data] can necessarily be said before it's done with reasonable results.

Comment: It might remain impossible in practice, but it's possible _in principle_ to calculate the impact of the model having been trained on any given inputs, versus it not having been, on the result; someone might figure out a neat trick for calculating that efficiently. RE Open Assistant: my bad, I thought they were only using the CC BY 4.0 data they're collecting themselves. And yes, no clue what the effects of cutting down the dataset would be for Firefox Translations, but we'd _still have a site_.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 "the model having been trained on any given inputs, versus it not having been" - May be overwhelmed by chaotic factors, resulting in a very different model in the same way just changing seeds or reordering training data does, and not provide a legally useful measure of impact. Butterfly flapping wings etc. "someone might figure out" - Even if we do get the very specific ruling about ML obligations and a good way to measure impact, I don't think the benefit (rather than replace images from problem models we can test and keep some of them) over just model name is all that significant.

Comment: I agree with this approach, though regarding "*providing model name may be more realistic.*", maybe also consider adding "the name of the service/app" in case they're not generating by themselves, thus they may not know the model used.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too broad, so I will provide a general overview in my answer.

## It depends.

If you are seeking guidance on a specific issue, it's important to provide specific details that align with the requirements and expectations of the answer you're seeking. This will ensure that you receive the best possible assistance.

If you have a question seeking general guidance, it's best to keep it general as well. Providing too much detail can be time-consuming and potentially confusing for those with moderation privileges who need to understand the answer requirements and expectations.